# Which structure function is G(x)?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, scattering

I found a question about structure functions where they ask what is the $F_2(x)$, $xF_3(x)$ and $G(x)$ shape as a function of $x$ (for a given $q^2=10$ GeV$^2$) and also as a function of $x$. I found this review:

http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/reviews/rpp2018-rev-structure-function-figs.pdf

and a couple of presentations:

https://www.uzh.ch/cmsssl/physik/dam/jcr:f51bc74c-1edc-47a3-9255-c29731f6b6c3/Lecture8New.pdf

where you can read about structure functions, but I did not find G(x) anywhere. Can somebody point to me where can I find information about it?

Comment: You should reference the question so we can have some context, there are several mentions of form factors/structure functions that have the name $G$ which include the Sachs electric and magnetic FFs $G_{E}$ and $G_{M}$. It may also be the dipole form factor $G_D$.

Comment: well, this is the problem, I found the question in an old exam and could not find any further reference, therefore I wanted to know if somebody knew what G(x) refers to. I think $G_E$ and $G_M$ refer to form factors, therefore they are not what I'm looking for here (but thanks!)

Comment: Structure function and form factor mean the same thing, form factor is just the newer term for them.

Comment: Can you give us some more context? Is there any polarization involved? In  the hadronic physics community, $\Delta G$ is sometimes used to denote the longitudinal spin dependent structure function of the proton, more often denoted as $g_1(x,Q^2)$.